# Resize the image propositionally until required file size is met

Tags: php, image, image-processing

Currently have a simple function that works, but it allows user to add big images. I want to allow all image uploads, but there should be a function that resizes the image until certain file size is met (like under 200kb for example)

```
if($_FILES['file']['size'] != 0){

        $uploadOk = 0;

        //image object
        $image = $_FILES['file'];

        //create unique name for file
        $imageRandomName = substr(md5(time()), 0, 5) . "-" . $image['name'];

        //upload dir
        $target_dir = "rest/user" . $_SESSION["username"] . "/events/" . $_SESSION["event_id"] . "/people/";

        //make folder for user if non exists
        if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
            mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
        }

        //file to be upload
        $target_file = $target_dir . base($imageRandomName);

        //get file type
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $check = getimagesize($image["tmp_name"]);

        if($check !== false){
            $uploadOk = 1;

        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

        if($uploadOk == 0){

            echo "noupload";

        } else {

            if ( move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $target_file ) ) {

                 //get file size on server
                $filesizeonserver = filesize($target_file);
                echo "file: ".$target_file." size: ".$filesizeonserver;
                $times = 0;
                if($filesizeonserver > 100000){
                    do{
                        $resized = resizeImage($target_file, "0.1");
                        $filesizeonserver = filesize($target_file);
                        $times++;    
                    } while ($filesizeonserver > 100000);
                    echo "resized ".$times." times";
                } else {

                }


                //mysql query

            } else {

                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";

            }
        }
    } else {
        //do mysql query
    }
```

resizeImage()

```
function resizeImage($file, $percent){
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $newwidth = $width-($width*$percent);
    $newheight = $height-($height*$percent);
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    $newImage = imagejpeg($thumb, $file, 100);
    return $newImage;
}
```

Now I am getting somewhere, I think I am really close achieving it, but for some weird reason I am getting image that has dimension of 1px width, 4px height and size of 4kb. Completely black image.

**In case you are thinking what image am adding to this function:
1,232,055 bytes, 1220 × 1829, 72dpi, JPEG**

EDIT: Okay now I think something is wrong with the resizeImage function. Since it works only first the first time. For some reason it fails to get image and renders it black and tiny.

EDIT2: Now I am getting image resized function, there was nothing wrong with it. I noticed that function keeps resizing the image till to its bitter end. I can see it in the find how it shrinks.

EDIT3: I located the problem. Now it seems that $filesizeonserver is getting always the first value and in do...while its not updating even thou i am setting it to change.

Comment: Do you want to limit file size to upload? You can simply check 
$_FILES['file']['size'] for that

Comment: The code snippet you have shown _literally starts with_ a check for whether the size of the uploaded file was not 0 ... and you can't come up with anything from there?

Comment: Quite unreasonable to rate question immediately down when clearly you don't understand the point. What I need is function that will resize the image  and I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: I have a snippet that can help you: https://github.com/kaduev13/image-tools

Comment: So you need to resize the image. What have you tried? Did you get to GD or ImageMagick? There's a confusion between file size and image size aka width x height in your code and question description. What are you trying to do? Limit file size or image size? Why are you telling us you need to resize width x height and then talk about file size at the same time? Please clarify the question. Things you say in comments !== things you explain in the question itself.

Comment: Let me clarify the title; User can add image of any size. Then php should resize the image until required file size is met. I am sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Your do..while loop always shrinks the image.  You should skip the resizing if it is already small enough.

Comment: If the `$image['size']` is greater than 200000 then your do-while loop will run forever. The value of `$image['size']`does not change inside the loop.

Comment: Okay, now I am getting somewhere. I am resizing image successfully thou only once, if I add do...while function to do the same until file is under somewhat kilobytes and returns really small image that is completely black.

Comment: Thank you for all helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$allowedFileTypes = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'];

        if (in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $allowedFileTypes)) {
            $imageType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            //allow file size under 10mb
            if($_FILES['file']['size'] < 10000000){

                //image object
                $image = $_FILES['file'];

                //so there is no same name files
                $imageRandomName = substr( md5( time() ), 0, 5 ) . "-" . $image['name'];

                //place where image is uploaded
                $target_dir = 'rest/user/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/events/' . $_SESSION['event_id'] . '/people/';

                //make folder for users
                if ( !file_exists( $target_dir ) ) {
                    mkdir( $target_dir, 0777, true );
                }

                //file to be uploded
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename( $imageRandomName );

                //get file type
                //$imageFileType = pathinfo( $target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

                $check = getimagesize($image["tmp_name"]);

                if ($check !== false) {
                    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                } else {
                    echo "File is not an image.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                //check if upload is ok
                if ( $uploadOk == 0 ) {
                    echo "Sorry cant upload";
                } else {
                    if ( move_uploaded_file($image["tmp_name"], $target_file ) ) {


                        //get file size on server
                        $filesizeonserver = filesize($target_file);

                        $times = 0;

                        if($filesizeonserver > 300000){
                            do{
                                clearstatcache(); 
                                $resized = resizeImage($target_file, 0.05, $imageType);
                                $filesizeonserver = filesize($target_file);
                                $times++;    
                            } while ($filesizeonserver > 300000);
                            echo "resized ".$times." times";
                        } else {

                        }

                        //sql query

                    } else {
                        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                    }
                }

            } else {
                //sql query
            }   
        } else {
            echo "wrongimagetype";
        }

resizeImage()

function resizeImage($file, $percent, $imageType){

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $newwidth = $width-($width*$percent);
    $newheight = $height-($height*$percent);

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    switch($imageType){
        case 'image/png': 
            $background = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 0, 0, 0);
            imagecolortransparent($thumb, $background);
            imagealphablending($thumb, false);
            imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $background = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 0, 0, 0);
            imagecolortransparent($thumb, $background);
            imagealphablending($thumb, false);
            imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        case 'image/jpg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
    }

    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    switch($imageType){
        case 'image/png': 
            $image = imagepng($thumb, $file, 0);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image = imagegif($file);
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        case 'image/jpg':
            $image = imagejpeg($thumb, $file, 100);
            break;
    }

    return $image;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
File is an image - image/jpeg.resized 17 times
```

Disclaimer: Whole things works thou image quality suffer a bit. Need to work on that.

Comment: Last comment on question was fixed by appending clearstatcache() before resize.

Comment: added allowedFileTypes png, gif, jpg and jpeg.

Comment: now it supports transparency, image quality does not match photoshop :D